# When are two vectors perpendicular?

Tags: vectors

Given vectors $\vec a, \vec b$ with $\|a\|=\sqrt{6}$ and $\|b\|=2\sqrt{3}$ and the angle between them is $45^\circ$

I have to find such $k$, that $a+kb$ is perpendicular to $b-2ka$

I am thinking of multiplying these vectors term by term and make it equal to $0$. I will get the equation: $ab-2ka^2+ab^2-2abm^2.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why did you stop at that point?

Comment: @AnotherUser Because I want to check if this way is correct or not.

Comment: What does $a^2$ mean for a vector? Try putting a along the x-axis and b at $45^o$ to that. Can you write down the components of a and b? What are then the components of (a+kb) and (b-2ka)? Just saw you mean dot product - that will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Recall that for any vector $\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{v}=|\textbf{v}|^2$. Plug in the magnitudes of the vectors you have, you can simplify the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is

$(\vec a+k\vec b)\cdot(\vec b-2k\vec a)\\
=(1-2k^2)(\vec a\cdot\vec b)+k(\vec b\cdot\vec b)-2k(\vec a\cdot\vec a)\\
=(1-2k^2)ab\cos45+kb^2-2ka^2\\
=(1-2k^2)(\sqrt{6})(2\sqrt{3})(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})+k(2\sqrt{3})^2-2k(\sqrt{6})^2\\
=6(1-2k^2)+12k-12k\\
=6(1-2k^2)=0.$

Hence, $k=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.